# Company asking for a 3 days test-- changed the process along the way

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, recruitment

I'm a software developer. I applied to a company and passed the initial screening.
After that, I passed a 3-hour technical test. 
I now am asked to write another technical test that would take 3 days.

Just before setting up this 3-day test-- after my 3-hr test, the company recruiter mentioned and scheduled an in-person interview. She checked the times with me, with the 3 others to participate in the interview, set the time up and sent me the invitation which I accepted.

After that, I received an email saying that she made a mistake, I have to do a 3-day test before the in-person.

I'm thinking of asking for doing the coding phase during the in-person interview. Phrasing something like "Would it be an option to move the coding phase to in-person interview."

How would this look?

I also now have mixed feelings about the company. They aren't sure about me. 3 days' time is too much to burn especially these days. And yet, I don't want to miss out on the opportunity.

TIA.

//--------------------------

UPDATE

The recruiter got back saying that they are changing the order-- the in-person next and the coding test after that.

During the conversation, I asked, rather clarified myself whether "3-days" was something that would require 3 straight days with my uninterrupted attention or just to give me time. Turns out to be the second.

The conversation went well. All resolved nicely.

Comment: @JoeStrazzerei already sent the email. will update here whatever happens. i'm on a project, it's busy! hoping that this wont sink though. i like the job.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere i think this is a reasonable request. my prof'l ego is also a bit sore. also figured-- if it'll sink out of this much, let it sink. fine company though.

Comment: In which country are you?

Comment: Why would this test take 3 days? Could it be that you are misinterpreting the complexity or requirements of this exercise? Are they presenting it as a "trial"?

Comment: @morsor it's the town, not the country. i moved here recently.  things are a bit different here. heard one guy actually bragging before the audience (a prof'l meetup) that he got one piece of work done by the job applicants. fuzzy startup culture dominating.

Answer (score 6):

You're well within your rights to decide that three days is too much time to spend on this and either ask for it to be changed, of course doing so may severely limit your chances of getting the job because they are well within *their* rights to decide that a candidate who doesn't want to follow their hiring process isn't someone they want to hire.

For what it's worth this seeming trend towards three day long tests (and similar) is a bit crap IMO, I understand why employers do it but I think in the long run it's counter-productive.